# How to Highlight current category on category and single page template?

Tags: single, categories, filters

On Wp Forums, I found a code that shows categories with images and it works very well. But I couldn't figure out how to highlight current category on *category.php* and *single.php*

Here is the code that i'm using

```
$cats = get_categories('hide_empty=0&child_of=2&orderby=count&number=99&order=asc');
foreach ((array)$cats as $cat) {
$catdesc = $cat->category_description;
echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat) . '" title="'. strip_tags($catdesc) .'">
        <li>
          <img src="' . get_home_url () . '/wp-content/uploads/' . $cat->slug. '.jpg" alt="' . $cat->cat_name . '" class="front-img" />
        </li>
      </a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
    <?php
        $current_category = get_the_category();
        /* 
           $current_category[0]->ID is holding the current category now. 
           If there are more than 1 categories for the post you should iterate
           through all of them and check if the current category you're 
           displaying is in there
        */

        $cats = get_categories('hide_empty=0&child_of=2&orderby=count&number=99&order=asc');
        foreach ((array)$cats as $cat) {
            $catdesc = $cat->category_description;
            ?>
            <li class="<?php echo ( ( $current_category[0]->ID === $cat->ID )? 'current' : '' ); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat); ?>" title="<?php echo strip_tags($catdesc); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_home_url (); ?>/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>" class="front-img">
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting error on this line, what is the problem?   `<li class="<?php echo ( $current_category[0]->ID === $cat->ID )? 'current' : '' ); ?>">` it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: I'll cross check and will let you know

Comment: Edited it. I was missing a openning '('

Comment: Thanks Nickolay, now code works! But it puts "current" class to every list item. I tried in single.php and category.php No luck.. here is the link http://bit.ly/1jKzCDa